# Como imprimir um elemento de uma lista a cada vez que um determinado método for chamado?

Tags: python, lista

Estou tentando fazer um jogo de expressões matemáticas em python, mas preciso que meu método MandaExp retorne uma expressão a cada vez que for chamado. Nesse método tenho uma lista chamada explist, onde diversas expressões estão organizadas de acordo com a seleção de dificuldade do usuário. Pesquisando achei algumas coisas mas da forma que está ele só retorna uma lista com os indices, ou seja, uma lista que vai de 0 a 430. Segue a parte do código:

```
class MotorDoJogoSP(object):
import operator
def MandaExp(self, dif):
    Dificultador.Sort = Dicio[dif]
    expr = Dificultador().Sort()
    explist = [operator.attrgetter('expressao')(x) for x in expr]
    resplist = [operator.attrgetter('resposta')(x) for x in expr]
    for e in range(len(explist)):
        yield e
```

Se faço `print list(MotorDoJogoSP().MandaExp(dif))` ele retorna: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, ..., 430]`

A saída esperada eram os elementos de explist, cada vez que fosse chamado o método sairia um elemento da lista, Exemplo: 36 + 0, 30/0, ...

Comment: Explique um pouco melhor. Qual era a saída esperada?

Answer (score 2):

Assim eu adicionava o indice a uma nova lista, a correção foi:

```
class MotorDoJogoSP(object):
import operator
def MandaExp(self, dif):
    Dificultador.Sort = Dicio[dif]
    expr = Dificultador().Sort()
    explist = [operator.attrgetter('expressao')(x) for x in expr]
    resplist = [operator.attrgetter('resposta')(x) for x in expr]
    for e in explist:
        yield e
```

E estou usando `next()` para imprimir um após o outro, quantas vezes for chamado.

Comment: Sim. Note que ao invéz de usar o `next` manualmente, você pode colocar sua chamada a função geradora  `MandaExp` direto num comando `for`:
`for expressao in MandaExp(dif):`